# android ndk - strange OutOfMemory error without memory leak

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, out-of-memory, mupdf

I'm working at a pdf reader app by using the native library from [muPDF](http://mupdf.com/). Unfortunately I'm encountering an OOM error after a lot of swiping through the pages. I'm using the following code to get some insights in the memory behavior (I've also used the Android Device Monitor before):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() // amount of allocated memory in the app heap

Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() // amount of allocated memory in the native heap
```

Now comes the strange thing...due swiping through the pages the returned values of these to methods are always stable, so actually it doesn't look like there would be a memory leak at all. But after some time an OOM error occurs although the values of these two methods are still like at the beginning.

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to prevent `OutOfMemoryError` from occurring by adding this in your application tag in your `AppManifest.xml`:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: I've added that already, but it's not a solution for my problem